# How to give beta and gamma in tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm trying to use normalization layer given by tensorflow. In that [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#batch_norm), there is a field to specify whether we are using beta or gamma values.

> **center:** If True, subtract `beta`. If False, `beta` is ignored.
>
> **scale:** If True, multiply by `gamma`. If False, `gamma` is not used. When the next layer is linear (also e.g. `nn.relu`), this can be disabled since the scaling can be done by the next layer.

But there is nowhere to input `beta` and `gamma` values into the function.

I need to know how can I input values for `beta` and `gamma`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided has specified the function as `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(*args, **kwargs)`.

Looks like you should be able to pass `beta` and `gamma` as `keyword arguments` or `**kwargs` like this:

```
tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(beta=value, gamma=value)
```

Comment: At least in Tensorflow 1.7, what you suggest is not possible. Was this possible in an earlier version?

Answer (score 0):

Beta and gamma are the learnable parameters of the batch normalization layer.

As you can see from the image below, these parameters are used to scale and shift the normalized values. The value you can pass to the `batch_norm` method, are the init value of these parameters.

[image: batch normalization]