# Passing beta and gamma into batch normalization

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I have a very specific use case where I need to manually pass in the parameters for the affine transform for batch norm (gamma and beta). As far as I can tell, neither `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` nor `tf.layers.batch_normalization` allow this (I believe the accepted answer to this related question is incorrect, at least for recent versions of Tensorflow: [How to give beta and gamma in tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998238/how-to-give-beta-and-gamma-in-tf-contrib-layers-batch-norm)).

Is there any way to accomplish this without manually defining a custom batch norm op that uses `tf.nn.batch_normalization` (I'd like Tensorflow to take care of maintaining the moving averages for mean and variance if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a specific value of Beta and Gamma, you can modify their initialiser like so :

```
tf.layers.batch_normalization(beta_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(your_beta),
                              gamma_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(your_gamma)
                              trainable=??)
```

Note the trainable argument. This will either allow the model to learn the optimal values of Beta and Gamma, or fix them to the value you provided.